# Successive lines of a comment are split up in knitr using R 3, but not R 2.15.3

Tags: r, knitr

I have an R script that I call from a python pipeline that knits a given .Rmd file.  However, the behavior of output from code blocks changes between versions of R, and I want the old behavior!

Here is the script I use to knit my .Rmd files:

```
#!/project/csbio/Scott/Software/R-x.xx.x/bin/Rscript

library(knitr)
library(formatR)

# Create filename
rmdFile <- paste(cmds[2], '.Rmd', sep = '')

# Set knitr, formatR options
render_jekyll(highlight = 'prettify')
options('tidy.opts' = list(width.cutoff = 60))
options('width' = 80)

# Knit to jekyll-compatible markdown
knit(input = rmdFile)
```

Here is my example .Rmd file:

````
```{r comment-1}
# Here is a comment...I want this comment to wrap onto the next line without a space inserted between them, but I have no idea what is causing this behavior, so I ask the kind strangers on stack overflow.
```
````

The result from knitting using R-2.15.3:

```
<pre><code class="prettyprint "># Here is a comment...I want this comment to wrap onto the next line
# without a space inserted between them, but I have no idea what is
# causing this behavior, so I ask the kind strangers on stack overflow.
</code></pre>
```

And the result from knitting using R-3.0.1:

```
<pre><code class="prettyprint "># Here is a comment...I want this comment to wrap onto the next line without</code></pre>



<pre><code class="prettyprint "># a space inserted between them, but I have no idea what is causing this</code></pre>



<pre><code class="prettyprint "># behavior, so I ask the kind strangers on stack overflow.</code></pre>
```

The result is that in R 3.0.1, comment lines are split up by white space every time they are wrapped.

My question is: what is causing this behavior between versions of R and how can I fix it?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: sorry, this is a bug, and I'll fix it soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be [fixed](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/commit/8c9881ece306659c61d562295d47d71bbdb5945e) in [knitr v1.4.12](https://github.com/yihui/knitr#readme) now, which will turn into knitr v1.5 eventually on CRAN.

Comment: Awesome, I'll check it out!  Why the difference between R versions?  I'm curious...

Comment: @scooteR that is completely my fault; I omitted this special case when I brought the change of the `source` hook in knitr v1.4